# Proof of a formula involving the product of two binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> Give at least two proofs that ${n \choose k}{k \choose j} = {n \choose j}{n-j \choose k-j}$.

This is my "proof" (we haven't gone over how to actually write proofs yet in class, so sorry if this is wrong formatting):

${n \choose k}{k \choose j} = {n \choose j}{n-j \choose k-j}$

$ \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!} = \frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!} \frac{(n-j)!}{(k-j)!(n-j-(k-j))!} $

$ \frac{ n! }{j!(n-k)!(k-j)!} = \frac{n!}{j!(k-j)!(n-k)!} $

$ \frac{ n! }{j!(n-k)!(k-j)!} = \frac{n!}{j!(n-k)!(k-j)!} $

However, I'm struggling to see how to prove something like this in two different ways. I tried playing with the "subsets of k elements from a set of n elements" definition, but nothing else that I tried made sense. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a hint: think about having $n$ objects and you are choosing $k$ objects from those of which $j\le k$ are special in some way. There are often alternate ways to sequence the choices ...

Comment: "but nothing else that I tried made sense" - What _did_ you try?

Answer (score 0):

The first way: choose first a $k$ element subset from an $n$ element set and after that choose from that now fixed $k$ element subset a $j$ element subset. There are ${n \choose k} {k \choose j}$ possibilities.
The second way: choose first a $j$ element subset from an $n$ element set and then extend this fix $j$ element set to a $k$ element subset of the $n$ element set. There are ${n \choose j} {n-j \choose k-j}$ possibilities. The both ways are equivalent, so the number of possibilities must be equal: ${n \choose k} {k \choose j} = {n \choose j} {n-j \choose k-j}$.